# Non-repeating random number in one cell together with text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a big datasheet with lots of individual named ranges that are dependently called upon by dropdown lists.

Since all names need to be unique I wanted to assign each name a unique ID. Ignoring the issue that I cant generate non-repeating random numbers this way, I also need the unique ID to be in the same cell as the rest of the name. So it should look something like "xyz-name_ID:rand()".
Is something like this possible? I would be a hassle to have to concatenate the name from an extra row.

Thanks & Cheers

Comment: use ROW() its unique, im guessing the ID doesn't have to be truly random, and can be ordered as long as its unique ?

Comment: yeah i tried similar methods bei ordering random numbers, but data is not written down in one column, but all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

So, I understand you to need, say, 1,000 unique values to assign to the ":rand()" portion of your Names. You want them assigned in random order, not some sorted order. The new ID's are to become Named Ranges and I have to assume you mean immediately, then will be used freely in the spreadsheet. I don't see a good other way to interpret things. And you want to form them without affecting the structure where they'll be used.

VBA would be your best bet for the bells and whistles I think you actually want in addition. It can take the list of existing Named Ranges, remove obvious duds like Print Ranges from the list, then tear the remainder apart for the random portions, generate 10 or 20 random values and see if they are in the random portions that exist already, pick one that isn't, and return the new ID in the cell you selected before starting the macro. I can't write that for you though so here's A solution that that doesn't involve anything more hassle-y than you should expect considering you do have to actually create the Named Range which you can't do from a formula in a cell. So:

Create a page that you can move out of the way when done. Use the following formula to create (for 1,000+ in the end) perhaps 2,000 values (so A1:A2000 perhaps):

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1000,9999)
```

Once you populate however many cells, copy and paste values so they don't keep changing on you. in the next column use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:$A$2000,"="&A1)
```

It will check each value in the list for how many identical values occur from it to the end of the list. So the formula would test A35 for how many times its value appears in the range A35:A2000... NOT in the whole list, just from it to the end. That's why the range `A1:$A$2000` is used (where usually you see the absolute reference first giving beginning down to the cell in question). Any value that appears again below itself will give a value >1. That value's last appearance in the list will give a 1 so one copy of it will be kept, but all the earlier appearances will give numbers >1.

Copy the list and paste values so no changes occur. Sort both columns by the "COUNT()" column, A-z so the >1 values will appear at the bottom. Go to the bottom and back up to where the values begin to be 1's. Highlight and clear the cell pairs that have "not-1" values. Now you have a list of unique, random values between 1000 and 9999, and still in a randomized order.

Next, go back to B1 and enter the following formula:

```
=IF(B1="","",B1&"_ID:"&A1)
```

This allows you to enter the chosen name in column C and see the full name, with it, the
_ID:" portion and the unique random value, appear in column C. You just copy it and paste values, then either 1) immediately go to the Named Ranges function dialogue and create a new range which you will see takes the value in the cell you just pasted values, so you don't have to type or paste that name and continue to the "Refers to" section entering the range however you like best, or 2) Hit F2, copy everything in the cell, go to the range that is getting names and highlight it, enter the Named Ranges dialogue and create a new Name, pasting the name you just created and seeing the "Refers to" section is filled in with the range you selected earlier. I prefer the second, as it's easy to carry the exact name with me and let Excel do the hard part of specifying the range from my selection of it but everyone's unique.

You pasted it as a value to ensure it never changes. Not really a concern here, but good practice. And that allows you to do method 2) above which not doing so would prevent the easy carrying of the name.

So, done, really. You had to go to the trouble to create the Named Range and creating the name itself first just by clicking somewhere and typing it first isn't too much more hassle. VBA could make even that go away, but it's not a trivial task. Creating the list in the first place took me three minutes and that involved experimenting to ensure I didn't mess it up and post the messed up formulas. You could even write a simple macro to go to the sheet with the list, and one to return to the exact sheet and place you left. Assign them corresponding shortcuts (like Ctrl-N to go to it, Alt-N to return to it). There are so many shortcuts already you'll step on one or two of them whatever you choose, so see what each of a pair does before doing it! Naturally, it could be ever so slightly more complicated, choosing the next untaken value, stepping through the work you'd do by hand, then returning control to you while never having left your place where you initiated it... Named Range already created and all the type a name, copy, paste values steps also done. If you enter the "xyz-name" part in the cell where you initiate it, it could use that for the name to make, and clear it from the cell when it returns control to you so it is pristine and ready for you to type your formula... no dialogue box needed in the macro so it would be one you could write using the recorder, not even fresh by hand. Spruce it up later to never leave the page you or your users are on with a line of code you can easily find "on the internet."

So with that recorder-type macro, it'd be almost like the more involved macro I mentioned at the start and all pretty hassle-free. Without that macro, still pretty quick and easy since it only adds a couple small bits of effort.

If you really might have a few thousand names someday, use five digits in the list-making `RANDBETWEEN()` to make list-size-reducing matches less likely and to keep the names standardized a little rather than all over the map, so to speak.